# Linux revert revoked permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I'm a sudo user on Ubuntu VM and I tried to give access to the other people with all of their permissions revoked (they just need the connection to the Postgres database).
I typed in:

```
sudo chmod 750 /
```

It worked for the other people. However, now even I can't execute sudo command or access the VM myself using PuTTY (I login and then PuTTY closes itself).

Is there any way I could login and revert permissions back?
Note that I'm not the owner of the VM so... maybe he could change it back or something?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: The root directory is normally owned by user `root`, group `root` with permissions 755 = `drwxr-xr-x`. Changing that to 750 = `drwxr-x---` will block **all access to all directories** on the system for any users that are not `root` or members of the group `root`. As a result a regular user's SSH session would then crash immediately because the user would not be able to even execute `/bin/bash`. Any member of the `root` group would be able to login normally.

Comment: Just for information, blindly running a `chmod` on the whole filesystem is guaranteed to have harmful effects. In this case you will probably manage to recover your system, but had you run the command recursively (`-R`) your only solution would have been to restore from backups or reinstall the server.

Answer (score -1):

> change it back

Yes, login as root and change all the permissions back to what they should be. Only....

1. Usually root access via ssh is disabled - you will likely need to log in on the console
2. You probably don't have the root password
3. If it was only the root directory: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec chmod 0755 ; chmod 0700 lost+found`

> or something?

A restore from backup or reinstall + restore data might be the safest way to restore functionality.

You need to speak to the person whom owns the host.

Comment: Since the `chmod` command indicated in the question was not recursive, just booting the VM to single-user/emergency mode and running a `chmod 755 /` as root will fully undo it. That will be much quicker than a full restore.

Comment: true - should read more carefully. Still needs root permissions `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec chmod 0755 ; chmod 0700 lost+found` should cover most of it if OP has root access.

Comment: Why do you use `find` at all? It's only the `/` directory that needs modifying. If you try changing anything else, you might open up access to directories that were originally restricted.

Comment: What if there are files there? What about symbolic links?

Comment: The command `sudo chmod 750 /` will only ever change the permissions on a single thing, the `/` directory. It will not change the permissions on _anything else_.  To revert that change, the command `chmod 755 /` should be issued in single user mode. Apart from describing how to get into single user mode, that should be the whole of the answer. Using `find` is a mistake in this instance.